# open a popup window when user enter fill the input field in a table using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a table containing input fields. to enter the time values by user.here i want the functionality is When they fill in the first start time, open a window that asks “do you want to include am/pm designations?” and if they say yes, include those am/pm options in the table.
how can i do this one by using javascript.

i write the following code

```
<div class="tbody">
<div class="tbc1" style="width:32%;">
Start Time</div>
</div>


<div class="tbody"><div class="tbc1" style="width:32%">
<input class="tblinput cd1st tsst tf" id="tsst" maxlength="5" type="text" style="width:45px;" placeholder="hh:mm"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onblur to handle when the user leaves an input.

Use confirm('my message') to display the question.

Something like this:

```
<input type="text" onblur="showMessage(this);" />

function showMessage(sender)
{
    if (confirm('do you want to...'))
    {
        document.getElementById('ampm').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Have a hidden am/pm field that can be displayed if required:

```
<select id="ampm" name="ampm" style="display: block">
 <option>am</option>
 <option>pm</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes ,it shows the popup .and here what i want is ,i want to placed 2 buttons as "yes","no" .if  they say yes, i want to include  those am/pm options in the table.can u tell me how can i do this ...

Comment: can anyone  tell me how can i add the 2 buttons as yes ,no .if  they say yes, i want to include those am/pm options in the table.can u tell me how can i do this

Comment: confirm doesn't allow you to change the button text. You can use a third party component instead if you wish. Example: [jquery Model Confirmation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Comment: without using component is not possible?

Comment: You could build your own but it's not worth the effort. You are aware jQuery is free to use and fully customisable? Don't reinvent the wheel.